# Is it possible to pass multiple objects or data to addtarget in a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to pass textview value on btn click on a particular cell index. 
my code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

-----
  [cell1.submitCommentBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftCommentBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   // here i want to pass textview object or its data  
---

}
```

Comment: you can pass array or nsdictionary for multiple object

Comment: Is there any option to pass data in selector ? I don't want to use any extra stuff for that.

Comment: is textview contain with cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thiss

**Using View Hierarchy**

```
   - (IBAction) leftCommentBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
        UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview; //change with your class
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; // using this indexpath you can get data from your datasource array
        cell.textView; // this is your textview 
    }
```

OR

**Using ConvertPoint**

```
- (IBAction) leftCommentBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
        CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
         YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textView; // this is your textview 
    }
```

Comment: [UITableViewCellContentView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff3ea4afd10

Comment: now check my update answer because you need to track your superView  in that lines so

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)leftCommentBtnClicked:(UIButton*)sender

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:(Your Table Name)];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(Your Table Name) indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
 }
```

Here you get IndexPath, so you can get all the value of that particular row.